# listings is not compatible with ctexbook

Tags: listings

My problem when I use `\documentclass[12pt,openany,a4paper,fancyhdr,oneside]{ctexbook}` with listings, all the following does not work.

```
\lstset{language=ThingML, caption={{\textit PingPong}}, label=thingml:example,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,frame=single,captionpos=b}

\begin{lstlisting}

message ping();

\end{lstlisting}
```

It seems that ctexbook is not compatible with listing as in some basic examples of listings work in article but not ctexbook. At the same time, I have to use to ctexbook, so the problem is that is there anyway to fix it or work around them.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to tex.SX! Can you provide a complete minimal working example? I cannot see any difference in output with this code when using `ctexbook` or the `article` class. Also: I don't see `ThingML` in the list of defined languages in the [documentation for `listings`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) - hence I do get undefined language errors, but I get them for both classes.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I was not expecting that. Well, I get undefined control of listings, so I guess the problem is something to do with listings. Anyway, here is the code.

Comment: The code cannot display correctly here, so I copied them in a txt and here is the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz_NmYxM5rG2ZmhENUx3aTFoMG8. Thanks a lot~!

Comment: I use the lualatex for some reason, and it says Undefined control sequence. \begin{lstlisting}

Comment: Thanks for the updated code - in future please edit your question when providing more information; this makes it easier for everyone.
Your code is missing `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` as well as `\usepackage{listings}` - I hope that is just an oversight.
Can you provide the exact error message you get?

Comment: I have written some published paper before, so I do include \begin{document} and \end{document} as well as \usepackage{listings}. Anyway, here is a snapshot of my latex workspace with error message. The weird thing is although I run into error message on the bottom line, the preview PDF does show the list correctly (on the right). The snapshot is https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz_NmYxM5rG2RElzV3dXSFV1R28. Thanks a lot!

Comment: ok, I can't see what the problem is here - I get similar errors, mabe with the complete error from the .log someone can point in the right direction..
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\lst@frameInit ... \z@ \ifdim \ht \strutbox <\cht`
`\@tempdima =\dimexpr \cht ...`
`l.12 \begin{lstlisting}`
                     
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\lst@frameInit ... \fi \ifdim \dp \strutbox <\cdp`
`\@tempdima =\dimexpr \cdp ...`
`l.12 \begin{lstlisting}`

Comment: Anyone have some idea on how to fix that? Does latex have some package that serves the same purpose or function as listings package. I guess I have to go around the listings and use something similar to help me print out the listing.